# Does $\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-}\left( \ln x \right)\left( \ln (1-x) \right)$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am trying to figure out whether
$\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-}\left( \ln x \right)\left( \ln (1-x) \right)$
exists. My approach:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-}\left( \ln x \right)\left( \ln (1-x) \right)=\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-}\left( \ln x \right)\left( \ln (\ln{1 \over x}) \right)$$
Now, we apply L'Hôpital's rule twice
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-} {\ln (\ln{1 \over x}) \over {1 \over \ln{x}}}=\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-}{(\ln x)^2 \over \ln{1 \over x}} = \lim\limits_{x\to 1^-}-2\ln x=0$$
Since the final limit exists, this would justify using L'Hôpital's rule. Is this approach correct?

Comment: How do you justify $\ln(1-x)=\ln(\ln(1/x))$?

Comment: @kingW3 Thanks, back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another approach:

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to1^-}\ \ln(x)\ln(1-x)&=\lim_{x\to1^-}\ \frac{\ln(x)}{x-1}(x-1)\ln(1-x)\\
&=-\lim_{x\to1^-}\ \frac{\ln(x)}{x-1}(1-x)\ln(1-x)\\
&=-\lim_{x\to1^-}\ \frac{\ln(x)-\ln(1)}{x-1}(1-x)\ln(1-x)\\
&=0
\end{align}
since
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to1^-}\ \frac{\ln(x)-\ln(1)}{x-1}&=:\ln'(1)=1
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\lim_{y\to0^+}\ y\ln y&=0.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Shorter, with *equivalents*:

First make the substitution $u=1-x$. The limits comes down to
$$\lim_{u\to 0^+}\ln(1-u)\ln u$$
Now $\;\ln(1-u)\sim_0-u$, so that
$$\lim_{u\to 0^+}\ln(1-u)\ln u=\lim_{u\to 0^+}(-u\ln u)=0.$$